# Tcpdf-Convert current webpage as PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

How to Convert current webpage as pdf using tcpdf? OR is there any other way to do that?

I want to include to pdf some contents in the current webpage. Can anyone tell the function to add current page content to tcpdf functions to print a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

USe HTML to PDF plugin. I have used dompdf and it works fine. Check link below.
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf